# What is System Program?

Tags: solana-program, systemprogram

I am confused about System Program. I found this explanation:

> One of the native programs is the System Program. This program can
> create new accounts, allocate account data, assign accounts to owning
> programs, transfer lamports from System Program owned accounts and pay
> transaction fees.

As far as I know, program is contract itself. I do not understand why we pass it here when we need to call the contract function

```
await program.rpc.create("Passing INitial message", {
      accounts: {
        calculator: calculator.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        // what is systemProgram? what does it do here?
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [calculator],
    });
```

Is there equivalent of System Program in Solidity?

Answer (score 3):

The System Program is Solana's core program. It's a contract that acts as a "library" of sorts and makes it more convenient to write other contracts.

For example it's needed here because it contains the root instruction to create accounts which is invoked for the initialization of the `calculator` account.

You can think of it as containing helper functions that are crucial for Solana contracts. Your program calls those functions for specific tasks.